# Join two tables but stop after first match and keep all rows from Left table

Tags: mysql, sql

Thanks in advance for taking the time to consider my problem. I have the following two tables:

pcidTable:

| PCID |
| --- |
| pcidtest1 |
| pcidtest1 |
| examplepcid2 |
| foopcid3 |
| barexample4 |

matchTable:

| Channel | Match String |
| --- | --- |
| TestCh1 | pcidtest |
| TestCh2 | pcid |
| TestCh3 | bar |

I want to combine the tables on the case that a `PCID` contains the `Match String` as a substring. This is fairly easy to do when the PCID only matches one row, as it would be a simple join. However, when a PCID contains `Match String`s from multiple rows, I only want it to join from the first "match". So, the result of these two tables would **ideally** look like the following:

IDEAL RESULT TABLE:

| PCID | Channel |
| --- | --- |
| pcidtest1 | TestCh1 |
| pcidtest1 | TestCh1 |
| examplepcid2 | TestCh2 |
| foopcid3 | TestCh2 |
| barexample4 | TestCh3 |

If I do a query like this, I get multiple rows for each the PCID rows with value "pcidtest1", because "pcidtest1" contains both "pcidtest" and "pcid":

```sql
-- Assume REGEXP_CONTAINS is a built in method that will return a
-- boolean signifying whether or not the second parameter is
-- a substring of the first.
SELECT pcidTable.pcid, matchTable.channel
FROM pcidTable
LEFT JOIN matchTable 
  ON REGEXP_CONTAINS(pcidTable.pcid, matchTable.match_string)
```

The above script would result in this table, which is not what I want because it contains multiple rows for each PCID that has multiple matches:

| PCID | Channel |
| --- | --- |
| pcidtest1 | TestCh1 |
| pcidtest1 | TestCh2 |
| pcidtest1 | TestCh1 |
| pcidtest1 | TestCh2 |
| examplepcid2 | TestCh2 |
| foopcid3 | TestCh2 |
| barexample4 | TestCh3 |

I instead want a table (see "IDEAL RESULT TABLE" above) that only contains one row for each row in the `pcidTable`, with the first match it sees in `matchTable`. Two things to note:

- We can assume that the `matchTable` is sorted by the length of the match string in descending order.
- This example would result in duplicate rows (pcidtest1 <--> TestCh1), but we would want to keep them as well.

Does anyone have any insight to how to approach this?

I tried writing a function that I pass a `PCID` string into to query against the `matchTable`, but the constraints of the problem do not allow me to use a subquery in a function, and it must be done in a join clause.

Comment: try incorporating a MIN so that you only get one row

Comment: Please see how to [TAG](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) your RDBMS

Comment: In an unordered set, how are you defining "first"?

Comment: @Stu, the `matchTable` is an ordered set, so I would only want the first match from that table.

Comment: Tables don't have an intrinsic order so @Stu 's comment still stands

Answer (score 0):

This is very inefficient but it will work -

```
WITH pcidNumbered AS (
  SELECT pcid, ROW_NUMBER() OVER() row_num
  FROM pcidTable
)
SELECT pcid, channel
FROM (
  SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY row_num ORDER BY LENGTH(match_string) DESC) c
  FROM pcidNumbered p
  LEFT JOIN matchTable m
    ON p.pcid LIKE CONCAT('%', m.match_string, '%')
) t
WHERE c = 1;
```